# How can I use my own AI model for image recognition in Unity with Vuforia?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, augmented-reality, image-recognition

what I want to do is to inject my own trained model for image recognition into Vuforia while using Unity.

All I know is that Vuforia uses a feature points detection algorithm, and that you can train a deep learning model using the Model Target Generator. I looked into the scripts in Unity in case something can be overridden, but did not find anything useful.

Because I do not want to build a whole AR system, but it appears these have their own recognition systems and interfering with the source code seems unideal.

Is there a way to do this ?
Or if you know how to replace the recognition system in Vuforia (or any AR SDK really), it would be delightful of you to share !

Anyway thanks and have a nice day !